# Random number generator with a specific amount of values

Tags: c++, random

Im making a random number generator, that should fill up a Vector.

The problem is that it needs to generate a random int's between min and max values, and generate a specific amount of number, and the values need to be placed so that there are equal amounts of each number.

for instance a max of 5 and a min of 1, while gerating 10 values it should come out as [1,4,3,2,5,3,5,4,2,1]

Comment: Can you share your attempts on how you approached this problem?

Comment: You fill the vector with `1,1,2,2,...,5,5`, then [shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) it. I'm assuming that it's a coincidence that each half of the vector has no repeating numbers? If it's not a coincidence, fill and shuffle each half separately.

Comment: Generating vector like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` and shuffling using [the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) may be easier.

Comment: Whe would you get for max of 5 and a min of 1, while generating 12 numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the vector length is multiple of the range of values needed, otherwise you cannot put them all in the same amount of time. In that case, you can just initialize it and then shuffle it:

```
void fillAndShuffle(std::vector<int>& vec, int min, int max, int amount) {
    int range = max - min + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        vec.push_back(min + (i % range));
    }
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::default_random_engine e(seed);
    std::shuffle(vec.begin(), vec.end(), e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add generated numbers to vector twice and use std::shuffle once